# What is the easiest way to block access from all countries except for one?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, firewall

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server which runs a game server and it's under heavy DDos attack right now. It's not a English-speaking community, so I don't need access from any other countries but mine. All of the attacking IPs are from different countries, except for my country.

So, I thought that I might block access from all countries except for mine to defeat DDos by iptables or something. What is the easiest way for this?

Thanks.

Comment: `iptables` was not design to identify country of `IP`, it's up to you to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of resources online for finding the IP blocks allocated to countries (generally for blocking purposes). Assuming you have adequate hardware router capacity or are running your routing on an adequate PC, you'd need to get the IP blocks for your country, set up a hardcoded remote access address for yourself, *then* set up rules to allow connections from IP blocks assigned to your country while blocking everything by default.

Unless you have physical access, set up your bypass first - it would stink to discover that you made a mistake in your permissions and the only rules being applied are the "block everything" ones.

Finally, if this is really a DDOS, blocking at your local firewall/router is probably not going to be terribly effective - a big part of the effectiveness of DDOS is not that it clogs up your servers (which it does) but that it clogs up the Internet connection from your ISP, or even the connection **to** your ISP. Filtering of the sort you may require would have to be done "upstream" from your connections.